# How to detect when a window has been dragged to another monitor in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I am trying to detect when the window of my WPF application is dragged between monitors, so I can change its size to fit the monitor it has been dragged to. I tried the following:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
        SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged;
}

public void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Changed");
}
```

However the `SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged` never gets called when I move the window to another monitor.

Also, I don't know if this is the best way to keep my application's sizes responsive.

Answer (score 1):

You can set in constructor of your window an event handler for `LocationChanged`:

```
this.LocationChanged += MainWindow_LocationChanged;
```

And check the monitor in the event handler:

```
private void MainWindow_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Screen screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromHandle(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
    //evaluate the screen variable
}
```

Comment: LocationChanged is raised when you are moving a window. Maybe if the app can detect end of the move it would be better. I didn't find any appropriate event for that in WPF. Is there any alternative to System.Windows.Forms for WPF?

Comment: @user2250152 I'm afraid there is no alternative in WPF, at least I'm not aware about it. The Answer is the way how it can be done. The OP can fit/adjust it to the needed requirements.